# VB.NET Add handler without event handler?

Tags: vb.net, eventhandler, addhandler

Is there a way for me to just specify an event handler without creating a new sub?

For example... Normally I would do something like the following:

```
AddHandler btn.click, EventHandler OpenDirectory

Private Sub OpenDirectory
     Process.Start("SomeDir")
End Sub
```

As you can see, the sub is just a one line of code.  So, can I simplify it down and do something like the following:

```
AddHandler btn.click, Process.Start("SomeDir")
```

I know the above doesn't work, but I'm hoping I'm being clear in what I want to do with the example.

Comment: Use an in-line one: `AddHandler btn.Click, Sub(snd, evt) Process.Start("SomeDir")`. It can substitute an explicit `EventHandler`  (you don't even need the parameters). Also see: [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions).

Comment: Make sure you remove that handler as well.

Comment: Wonderbar!  Thanks.  Learn something new everyday.